# python 3.12 typing override function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, python-3.12

this type of **defining function** in python looks a little bit weird to me

```
def override[F: type](method: F, /) -> F:...
```

what is the meaning of `[F: type]` exactly?

is it something like, **new way of defining parameter type before defining a function parameter**?
I cannot found anything about it and I don't know what to search.

I would be thankful if someone can explain this to me.

if you're using python 3.12, this example is available for you by just importing `override` function from `typing` module.

you can press `Ctrl + LMB` on `override` function to see the code I highlighted above.

Comment: "you can press Ctrl + LMB on override function to see the code I highlighted above." - I don't understand how you're expecting that to work. Stack Overflow doesn't implement any functionality like that. If you're talking about something that works for you when you edit the code, that depends on **your IDE** - which could be completely different in any other IDE, and we don't know which one you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new syntax for defining generic types. It's described [here in PEP-695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/):

> Here is an example of a generic function today.
>
> ```
> from typing import TypeVar
>
> _T = TypeVar("_T")
>
> def func(a: _T, b: _T) -> _T:
>     ...
> ```
>
> And the new syntax.
>
> ```
> def func[T](a: T, b: T) -> T:
>     ...
> ```

And the type following the colon in for specifying a [bound](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/#upper-bound-specification).